# How to check how many days left on Windows developer license (Store apps) license? Able to force renew?

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, licensing

I'm fairly frequently in situations where I have little or no access to the internet.  Visual Studio requires users to renew their Store Apps developer license every 30 days.  Is there a way for me to check how many days are left before I have to renew?  And can I do a "force renew" immediately, if I know my license expires in 4 days, but I know I will not have internet access for the next week?  I'd want to renew my license immediately so that I can still occasionally work with Visual Studio app development during that whole week.

Comment: Last I checked, it's not very scriptable. Maybe add a reminder or event to a calendar every 30 days to renew a few days in advance?

Answer (score 0):

With your computer connected online...

1) start visual studio. 
2) open up an existing Windows Store project.
3) select "PROJECT" from menu. 
4) then select "Store" -> "Aquire Developer License" 
5) click on "Agree" button in the following dialog box.

*I have visual studio 2013, but I guess it should be the same for VS 2012.